# Error al modificar un objeto dentro de un ciclo

Tags: android, loops, ciclos

Como dice el titulo, tengo un problema al tratar de modificar un atributo de un objeto al momento de ser recorrido; lo que hago es crear un ciclo para recorrer un listado, dentro de este ciclo creo un objeto el cual voy a llenar desde una base de datos SQLite, y al momento de modificar uno de los atributos me sale un error de NullPointerException, lo curioso es que sale el error tras haber hecho ya un ciclo, y si no modifico el objeto los objetos se llenan bien.

```
selected = "0"+String.valueOf(i+1);
        Log.e("onItemSelected",selected);
        aList = sqLiteAccumulated.getAllAccumulated(selected);

        sqLiteItems = new SQLiteItems(ItemActivity.this);
        pList = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();
        Log.e("aList size", aList.size()+"");
        for (int j = 0; j<aList.size(); j++){
            productModel = new ProductModel();
            productModel = sqLiteItems.readItem(aList.get(j).getMI2_ARTIC());
            productModel.setMI_ACT(Float.parseFloat(aList.get(i).getMI2_ACT()));
            if (productModel!=null){
                pList.add(productModel);
            }
        }
```

y el log me muestra esto

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void co.dibso.gomezvelasquezvendedores.Modelo.ProductModel.setMI_ACT(float)' on a null object reference
```

pero esto ocurre después de haber pasado ya un ciclo.

Comment: Deberias de verificar si el metodo readItem returna null antes de ejecutar el metodo `setMI_ACT` y asi te evitarias el error.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: size no devuelve un elemento mas de lo que tiene el array en realidad?? cuando devuelve un 1.. el elemento es en realidad el 0, el unico que hay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El metodo `readItem` esta retornando null y aun asi ejecutas el metodo `setMI_ACT` sin validar que no este null.

Intenta verificar primero si esta null y luego ejecutas el metodo:

```
    //...
    for (int j = 0; j<aList.size(); j++){
        productModel = new ProductModel();
        productModel = sqLiteItems.readItem(aList.get(j).getMI2_ARTIC());
        if (productModel!=null){
            productModel
            .setMI_ACT(Float.parseFloat(aList.get(i).getMI2_ACT()));
            pList.add(productModel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eso era, se me paso por alto ese punto aun cuando ya estaba validando el producto como tal para agregarlo a la lista, gracias.

Comment: Puedes aceptar la respuesta si era lo que esperabas.